# Did ruby install wrong?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, homebrew

I followed 2 different guides to install ruby on OSX and I think I messed some things up. Now that I know what I'm doing a bit more I have a feeling something is wrong. I'd like to 'start fresh' but i dont know what to remove safely (I dont mind re-installing everything. I have nothing super important)

I first used rvm and then decided i wanted to use homebrew. I uninstalled rails with rvm and then 'imploded' rvm. I then installed homebrew and then brew install rails 1.9.3

Although... when i run gem install xxx, all my gems seem to be in a weird path?

For instance, sinatra.rb is installed here:

```
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sinatra-1.3.1/lib
```

Notice it says 1.9.1, yet when I run

```
ruby -v
```

I get 1.9.3p0

and **which ruby** i get this

```
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p0/bin/ruby
```

If i do which [rails,git,mysql,whatever]

they all seem to point to Cellar.

as a sidenote, i have two versions of sinatra.rb on my computer... this is where the other one is (although the one I'm pretty sure it's not using).

```
/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.7.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/sinatra-1.2.0/lib
```

kind of ridiculous...

I'm not sure whats going on here.

This is my path if that helps:

```
export LSCOLORS="GxGxBxDxCxEgEdxbxgxcxd"
export CLICOLOR=1
export PATH=/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p0/bin:/usr/local/mysql-5.5.18-osx10.6-x86_64/bin:/usr/local/bin:$PATH
```

Comment: I strongly suggest you to use [rvm](http://beginrescueend.com/) as it (usually) simplyfies the process of installing and using ruby on Mac or *nix.

Comment: /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p0/bin/gem

Comment: Also i just tried a simple sinatra test, include sinatra in main.rb and it says undefined method `get' for main:Object (NoMethodError). SO im guessing its not seeing sinatra at all

Comment: Could you post the output of `gem install sinatra --verbose` to pastie/pastebin and link us?

Comment: With the Windows installer for Ruby 1.9.3 it is the same. The libs are in `$RUBYDIR/lib/ruby/1.9.1` and the gems go to `$RUBYDIR/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1`. Despite that, it is working normally. I guess they just did not update the pathes for the minor revision.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's fine. You are using 1.9.3. The gems are installed under a 1.9.1 directory, to distinguish them from gems installed for 1.8.7 (some gems that work with the 1.9 series don't with 1.8, and vice-versa). 1.9.1 was the first released version of the 1.9 series.